# My electron armv7l build exits with Segmentation Fault

Tags: electron, cross-compiling

I have an armv7l board that needs electron.  With the assistance of buildroot, I have been able to get the latest version of electron via 'npm install' although I want to build electron myself and deploy it onto my board.  I have followed electron's build instructions for cross-compiling it [link](https://electronjs.org/docs/development/build-instructions-gn) and I have created a build that sort of executes. The output from the electron build is a file called dist.zip.  I copied this over to my target, unzipped, and executed electron although it quickly exited with a segmentation fault.  I'm confident that the build is for the correct processor.

Here are the contents that exist inside of dist.zip.

```
drwxr-xr-x 5 docker-user docker-user     4096 Aug 22 22:31 .
drwxr-xr-x 8 docker-user docker-user     4096 Aug 22 22:29 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user     1060 Aug 10 05:36 LICENSE
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user  3993441 Aug 23 02:02 LICENSES.chromium.html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 docker-user docker-user  4224508 Aug 23 05:17 chrome-sandbox
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user   116794 Aug 23 03:59 chrome_100_percent.pak
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user   175786 Aug 23 03:59 chrome_200_percent.pak
-rwxr-xr-x 1 docker-user docker-user 78589028 Aug 23 05:17 electron
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user 10425616 Aug 10 06:10 icudtl.dat
-rwxr-xr-x 1 docker-user docker-user   161468 Aug 23 05:17 libEGL.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 docker-user docker-user  5089240 Aug 23 05:17 libGLESv2.so
-rwxr-xr-x 1 docker-user docker-user  1962076 Aug 23 05:17 libffmpeg.so
drwxr-xr-x 2 docker-user docker-user     4096 Aug 22 22:31 locales
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user    82118 Aug 23 02:35 natives_blob.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 docker-user docker-user     4096 Aug 22 22:31 resources
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user  8438393 Aug 23 03:59 resources.pak
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user   279912 Aug 23 05:14 snapshot_blob.bin
drwxr-xr-x 2 docker-user docker-user     4096 Aug 22 22:31 swiftshader
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user   612184 Aug 23 05:15 v8_context_snapshot.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 docker-user docker-user       22 Aug 10 05:36 version
```

I then ran it as seen below and got a fault.

```
./electron: /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by ./electron)
./electron: /usr/lib/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by ./electron)
./electron: /usr/lib/libasound.so.2: no version information available (required by ./electron)
Segmentation fault
```

I then ran it with strace and this is what I saw.

```
mprotect(0x75618000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x75be8000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0x760ab000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
--- SIGSEGV {si_signo=SIGSEGV, si_code=SEGV_ACCERR, si_addr=0x76bebfdc} ---
+++ killed by SIGSEGV +++
Segmentation fault
#
```

I ran this with gdb and did a backtrace and below is what I see.

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x76fc7048 in relocate_pc24.12735.isra.0 () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
(gdb) bt
#0  0x76fc7048 in relocate_pc24.12735.isra.0 () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#1  0x76fc7a76 in _dl_relocate_object () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#2  0x76fc1730 in dl_main () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#3  0x76fcecc4 in _dl_sysdep_start () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#4  0x76fc2906 in _dl_start_final () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#5  0x76fc2ad0 in _dl_start () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#6  0x76fbfa50 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
#7  0x76fbfa50 in _start () from /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.